# Mongoose subdocument meet multiple conditions simultaneously

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema set up with `Resource`, `Skill`, and `ResourceSkillLevel`.  The first two are essentially just names, and the latter has a reference to the resource, the skill, and the level.  I would like to select all `Resource`s that match certain skill levels simultaneously.

---

### Schema

```
// Omitting fields that don't matter for the purpose of the question
ResourceSchema = new Schema({name: String});
SkillSchema = new Schema({name: String});
ResourceSkillLevelSchema = new Schema({                                         
    "resource": {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Resource"},                       
    "skill": {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Skill"},                             
    "level": {type: Number, min: 1, max: 5}                                     
});
```

---

### Problem

Currently I have:

```
ResourceSkillLevel.find({$and: [
    {skill: "node.js", level: {$gte: 3}},
    {skill: "mongodb", level: {$gte: 3}},
]})
```

This would return `ResourceSkillLevel` entries, but there are two problems:

- This condition is impossible since one `ResourceSkillLevel` entry cannot meet both conditions simultaneously
- I want to get `Resource` entries that satisfy all of these conditions.  If I got `ResourceSkillLevel` entries I could get the `Resource` from them, but I'm sure there is a simpler way.

---

### Requirement

In case you don't understand, what I need is a way to get all `Resource` entries that match the required `ResourceSkillLevel` entries simultaneously.  That is, based on the query above I should be able to get a `Resource` that has 4 in node.js *and* mongodb, but *not* get a resource that has only 2 in node.js or does not have a skill level for either of the skills at all.

Comment: Can you update your question to include your schemas?

Comment: I don't see how your "Currently I have" query could be working at all.  MongoDB doesn't support joins, so you can only reference skills by their `_id` value when querying `ResourceSkillLevel`.  So you'd have to do this using multiple, separate queries.

Comment: @JohnnyHK what I have is not working; that is sort of an example of what I would like to use, but I know it's wrong.  I don't really understand how to put the multiple queries together is the problem.  I came up with a solution using `or` and then comparing the results by Resource._id to the number of skills to match, but that seems very convoluted;  I think there has to be a better way, even if it means changing the schema

Comment: Is Level not just a property of the Skill that the Resource has? It looks like you are separating out the parts of your model a bit too much.

Comment: @AlistairNelson it is not; different resources can have different skill levels for different skills.  For example one resource will have 4 in node.js but another will have 2 in node.js

Comment: But the actual Level is really just a number attached to a Skill is it not?

Comment: @AlistairNelson yeah that's exactly what it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My way of implementing this would be to change the schemas as follows:

```
SkillSchema = new Schema({name: String, level: {type: Number, min: 1, max: 5}});
ResourceSchema = new Schema({name: String, Skills: [SkillSchema]});
```

I forget if mongoose allows for embedding schemas like this...

Then you can do a query like so:

```
Resource.find({skills: [{"name": "nodejs", "level": 2},{"name": "mongodb", "level": 3}]})
```

This should get you most of the way to getting this right.

---

Edit to show better way to do this.

You could store the Skills in their own collection and then just store an array of Skills in the Resource schema but with the following fields:

```
SkillSchema = new Schema({name: String });
ResourceSchema = new Schema({name: String, Skills: [{skill_id: String, level: {type: Number, min: 1, max: 5}}]});
```

This way you can have the single collection of skills and you then reference the _id of the Skill in the Skills collection on the Resource.

Your query then looks like:

```
Resource.find({skills: [{"skill_id": skill id from SkillSchema collection, "level": 2},{"skill_id": skill id from SkillSchema collection, "level": 3}]})
```

This should work for you

Comment: The problem with this is that now there is nothing that enforces unique skill names.  I also need to be able to *get* the list of skills for display so you can select a skill to add -- that is to say that skills need to be able to exist without a single resource even referencing them.

Comment: How is the data going to get in to the database? Through a web site or some other admin or directly added? If the former then it is there that you enforce your unique names, if the latter then...

Comment: The edit shows a better way of doing this, using the ids of the individual skills rather than a name

Comment: That's a great start, but then how do I effectively do the query above (where a resource needs to meet all the skill conditions simultaneously).  Do I need to use `.populate` to be able to query the skill levels by name?

Comment: The queries above will match multiple items in the skills array. To be able to query them by skill name you would need to do 2 queries, one to use the name of the skill to get the _id and then use that _id to query the Resources collection. Or, you could store the name of the skill, taken from the SkillsSchema collection, along with the _id to allow you to query by either.

Comment: Is there any way to enforce unicity of the "skill" entry via the Resource schema or will I just have to add middleware that checks the existence of a skill when attempting to push?

Comment: There is an [addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/addToSet/) operator that may help you with this, although the fact that the level would likely be different it may not help.